# IP route operation not permitted when executed by script

Tags: bash, sudo, iproute

I have a simple script that I want to use to change the default route using `ip route replace default via $myIP dev $Eth`. The script runs fine when executed using `sudo ./test.sh` but it fails when my user tries to execute it (`sudo -H -u www-data ./test.sh`).

I already tried giving root access to `www-data` to both the script and the commands in visudo but it still trows this error `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`. How can I give my user access to that command?

visudo

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/www/test.sh
www-data ALL=(root) /sbin/ip
www-data ALL=(root) /sbin/route
```

Comment: It would help to see the script. Anyway did you check AppArmor or SELinux errors too (usually in /var/log/audit/ ) ?

Comment: You also don't say in which file you made those changes with `visudo`.